# How to give run time permission for marshmallow for read SMS from inbox in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have applied multiple code but it's show me checkSelfPermission() and shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale methods not exits, please help me..

I used brodcast receiver class for reading SMS it's working fine for jellybean to lolipop but not for marshmallow and lower versions than jellybean like icecream sandwitch, how can i make application to compatible for all android versions,

please guide me step by step because i'm new for this and please give me example also.

hear is my code for read sms permission..

```
public void getpermission(){


    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_SINGLE_PERMISSION);

            // REQUEST_CODE_ASK_SINGLE_PERMISSION is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
```

Comment: *i'm new for this* -- Then you may want to know Eclipse has been deprecated for Android development for a long time now (not that switching would fix your issues)

Answer (score 7):

you can do it by extending this given class in your Activity,

```
public class BasePermissionAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String APP_NAME = "APP_NAME";
private final static int REQUEST_READ_SMS_PERMISSION = 3004;
public final static String READ_SMS_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED = "Please allow " + APP_NAME + " to access your SMS from setting";

RequestPermissionAction onPermissionCallBack;

private boolean checkReadSMSPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public void getReadSMSPermission(RequestPermissionAction onPermissionCallBack) {
    this.onPermissionCallBack = onPermissionCallBack;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!checkReadSMSPermission()) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, REQUEST_READ_SMS_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
    }
    if (onPermissionCallBack != null)
        onPermissionCallBack.permissionGranted();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (REQUEST_READ_SMS_PERMISSION == requestCode) {
            // TODO Request Granted for READ_SMS.
            System.out.println("REQUEST_READ_SMS_PERMISSION Permission Granted");
        }
        if (onPermissionCallBack != null)
            onPermissionCallBack.permissionGranted();

    } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        if (REQUEST_READ_SMS_PERMISSION == requestCode) {
            // TODO REQUEST_READ_SMS_PERMISSION Permission is not Granted.
            // TODO Request Not Granted.


            // This code is for get permission from setting.
            //final Intent i = new Intent();
            //i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            //i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            //i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            //startActivity(i);
        }
        if (onPermissionCallBack != null)
            onPermissionCallBack.permissionDenied();
    }
}

public interface RequestPermissionAction {
    void permissionDenied();

    void permissionGranted();
}

}
```

like this

```
public class ActivityMain extends BasePermissionAppCompatActivity
```

now in your ActivityMain you can get permission by this code block

```
getReadSMSPermission(new RequestPermissionAction() {
@Override
public void permissionDenied() {
    // Call Back, when permission is Denied
    // TODO, task after permission is not greante
}

@Override
public void permissionGranted() {
    // Call Back, when permission is Granted
    // TODO, task after permission is greante
}
});
```

And One more thing, you need to add a permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should read document https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
so, as per document

> ```
> private static finat int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS = 101;
>
> // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
> if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
>                 Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
>         != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>     // Should we show an explanation?
>     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
>             Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
>
>         // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
>         // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
>         // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
>
>     } else {
>
>         // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
>
>         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
>                 new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
>                 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS);
>
>         // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
>         // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
>         // result of the request.
>     }
> }
> ```

and you have to Handle the permissions request response.

> ```
> @Override
> public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS: {
>             // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>             if (grantResults.length > 0
>                 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>                 // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                 // contacts-related task you need to do.
>
>             } else {
>
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'case' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method:

```
     public boolean checkPermissionSMS(final Context context, final String[] PERMISSIONS, final int Requestcode) {
            int currentApiversion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;


            if (currentApiversion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setMessage("Read SMS permission is necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               //in fragment
                        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS,Requestcode);

//in activity
                  ActivityCompact.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this,PERMISSIONS,Requestcode);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                        alert.show();

                    } else {
//in fragment
                        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS,Requestcode);

//in activity
                  ActivityCompact.requestPermissions(YourActivty.this,PERMISSIONS,Requestcode);
                    }
                    return false;

                } else
                    return true;
            } else
                return true;

        }

and then in onrequestPermissionresult:

     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if(requestCode==100)
            {
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    //do your functionality
                }
            }
        }
```

and call the method like this:

```
checkPermissionSMS(context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},100);
```

when you request permission like this:

```
requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS,Requestcode);
```

then the method onRequestPermissionResult is searched in the **calling Fragment**

when you request permission like this:

```
ActivityCompact.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this,PERMISSIONS,Requestcode);
```

then the method onRequestPermissionREsult is searched in the **calling activity**.

Comment: @ Satish silveri, it show me error The method requestPermissions(String[], int) is undefined for the type SMSReceiver and The method shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity, String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat

Comment: @Zilu-if you are using this method in fragment just dont add ActivityCompact in front of any method and if you are using this method in activity then use ActivityCompact before all methods! it would not give error! In fragment the method shouldshowRequestPermission will be called like shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale( getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_SMS))

Comment: cannot find symbol ActivityCompat   is showing. Please provide solution