# Remove permission for a specific phone version in gradle script

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions

I am wondering if there is a way to remove some permission added in manifest file from gradle file, when building project.

Example: I have a  permission in manifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Now, I want to achieve, if user has a device above 29, do not ask for that specific permission, else ask for it. I can not find any documents(if that is even possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 29) {
    // ask permission programmatically, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798731/how-to-give-run-time-permission-for-marshmallow-for-read-sms-from-inbox-in-eclip
} else {
    // whatever
}
```

If you're under android Donut you have to use a different class.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993924/get-android-api-level-of-phone-currently-running-my-application).

Comment: Hi, tanx! Will try and get back to you how it went.